# Converting time data frame to numeric data

Tags: r, dataframe, time, numeric

I have a data frame in the time format. i need to change it to numeric data. 
I used the following format but i am not sure if it is correct since the values changes in numeric format.

```
Photoperiod
08:52:41
08:53:35
08:54:33
08:55:36
08:56:44
08:57:55
08:59:11
09:00:31
09:01:55
09:03:23
09:04:55
09:06:31
09:08:10
09:09:53
09:11:40
```

---

```
DF<- read.csv2(file="DF.csv")
DF.a <-as.POSIXct(DF, format = "%H:%M:%S")

library(data.table)

DF.B<- lapply(DF.a , function(x) as.numeric(as.ITime(x)) / 3600)
```

Comment: Where's the problem? First two time have a difference of ~1 minute. This is 1/60 ~0.016. If you look at the difference between first two times it's 0.015.

Comment: What values did you expect to see? The function `as.numeric(as.ITime(x))/3600` would give time in terms of number of hours (up to 24). You can check for example that `as.numeric(as.ITime("12:00:00"))/3600` returns 12, `as.numeric(as.ITime("23:59:59"))/3600` returns 23.99972, & so on.

Comment: My data frame is the daylight data, so 14:25:30 means 14 hours and 25 min of daylight, i dont know if i use  as.numeric(as.ITime(x))/3600 i crush my data or not. Just get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (very) similar question was asked yesterday in the [SO in portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230114/como-converter-horaminutossegundos-para-numero-decimal-no-r). The answer by Marcus Nunes may give what you want.

Note that he calls the function `HoraDecimal`, portuguese for 'DecimalHour'.

```
HoraDecimal <- function(x){
  sum(unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, split=":"), as.numeric)) * c(1, 1/60, 1/3600))
}

x <-  "02:20:00"
HoraDecimal(x)
[1] 2.333333

y <-  "00:50:00"
HoraDecimal(y)
[1] 0.8333333

z <- "3:30:30"
HoraDecimal(z)
[1] 3.508333
```

I've made a suggestion in the comments section, to use `sapply` instead of `unlist(lapply(...))`. The following is such a version. With name changed to english.

```
DecimalHour <- function(x){
  sum(sapply(strsplit(x, split=":"), as.numeric) * c(1, 1/60, 1/3600))
}

DecimalHour(x)
DecimalHour(y)
DecimalHour(z)
```

The conversion method is the same, it's still Marcus' function and if you find it usefull the credits should go to him.

Comment: Wouldn't at `%*%` works here

Comment: @akrun The matrix multiply returns a `matrix`. I don't believe that's what the OP wants.